# How to define the shape of a map type in Dart

Tags: typescript, dart

In typescript:

```
const someMap = {a: "hi", b: 3}; // TS can understand the type of someMap is {a:string, b:number}.

const greet = someMap.a; // TS knows greet is string.

const someMapList: {a:string, b:number}[] = [{a: "hi", b: 3},{a: "bye", b:5}];
someMapList.map((m)=> {
    // TS can understand the shape of m.
})
```

However in Dart, I only find `Map<K,V>`. How to achieve the same tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Typescript/Javascript maps are more like `Objects`, so it's possible to define their shape like u're trying to. But in Dart that's not the case.

To achieve the same result you must create your on `Object`

```
class CustomObject {
  final string a;
  final int b;
  
  CustomObject(this.a, this.b);

}
```